# CSS animated background is not applied to entire page

Tags: css, animation, background

So I recently discovered the really exciting animation features of CSS3 and applied an animation to the background of my website:

http://ryanhammond.us/

My problem with it is that the animation only applies to the portion of the page that is visible within the browser window upon loading. If you go to the link above and scroll down, you'll see what I mean, the background image is animated in the top portion of the website, but not as you scroll down the page...

Does anyone know of a way around this, so that the bg animation applies to the entire page?

Here are the relevent portions of my CSS code:

```
body
{
background-image:url('images/patterntest2.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat;
-webkit-animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
   -moz-animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
     -o-animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
        animation:bgscroll 20s infinite linear;
}

/*////////////////////////////////////////////////
--------------------------------------------------
*   Animations
-------------------------------------------------- 
////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

@-webkit-keyframes bgscroll {
from {background-position:0 0;}
to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes bgscroll {
from {background-position:0 0;}
to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes bgscroll {
from {background-position:0 0;}
to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}

@-o-keyframes bgscroll {
from {background-position:0 0;}
to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}

@keyframes bgscroll {
from {background-position:0 0;}
to {background-position:0 -520px;}
}
```

Comment: Firefox 19 here, and it works all the way down the page.

Comment: Animation is a *new* feature? We had this way back in the 90s when Geocities was still around. It was annoying then, and it's still annoying now.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome, and it's working fine for me as well.
But if  you're having an issue, I suppose you could try setting

```
background-size: cover;
```

and maybe that'll fix your issue.

Comment: I also have Chrome latest (25.something) on Windows 7, and it is *not* working for me. Like the question describes, the scrolling effect works only in the area that is initially visible. It is broken when you scroll down. Adding `background-size: cover;` did not fix it.